# login view will not come after remember me button pressed.Must come second view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

i need some code for my task:
i.e.
if any user login and do remember for username and password then in next launch login view must not come. infact it will come second view.

How it will possible.
Wait for your ideas

Thanks,

Comment: set the Bool variable for do remember condition and add views depending on that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When you login for the first time, save username and password in
   [Keychain](http://log.scifihifi.com/post/55837387/simple-iphone-keychain-code) if user selected "remember me".
2. Next time you launch the app get User credentials from Keychain, and
   do the login process yourself. If login process takes time, use an
   activity indicator or something to make user wait.
3. If login is successfull, call your second View.
4. Whenever user click logout (if you have a logout button), make sure
   to remove credentials from keychain. So on next launch, since there is no credential in keychain, login page must be shown

Comment: Related reading.. http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2011/01/05/using-keychain-to-store-passwords-ios-iphone-ipad

Comment: i dont have any idea to do this can you show some code and where to start working this.give me some sample project what you have done for this